# unexpected end of declaration for class variable

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, global-variables, variable-declaration

I am facing weird error: unexpected end of declaration. And I am very sure that there is no typo. Please help.

```
package test.anyname;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   boolean ty= true;
   ty= false;       // Error occurred at this line
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
}
```

Comment: The `ty= false;` statement must be inside some method.

Comment: @Eran Why must `ty = false;` be inside a method?

Comment: If you want ty to be "false" why should you initialize with "true" or you can change value of ty inside onCreate() to "false"

Comment: @VívêkBåräì I am new to this and it is my first script. But from what i have learnt this should be allowed, right?

Comment: @D5fgj the fact there is a compiler error is a clear indication that this is not allowed.

Comment: According to java's algorithm you cannot assign value to variable out side method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things which you can write directly inside a class body are:

- Field declarations (e.g. `boolean ty= true;`)
- Method declarations (e.g. `@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { ... }`)
- Constructors
- Declarations of nested interfaces and classes
- Static and instance initializers

`ty = false;` is an assignment, which is none of these, so it is not allowed.

Comment: How about something like `Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();` ? Because it can be run without error

Comment: That is a field declaration, with an initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a variable only once and you can't change this variable once again outside of some method. Then, you should do this in a method.

```
package test.anyname;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   boolean ty = false; // you can initialize only once

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }

   void changeTy() {
      ty = !ty;
   }
}
```

Comment: A couple of points (and I'm mostly nitpicking): 1) you can actually initialize a variable multiple times: `boolean ty = ty = ty = false;` is (perhaps surprisingly) legal; 2) you can change the variable in an instance initializer (e.g. `boolean ty = false; {ty = true;}`), which isn't a method.